# Microsoft Teams shows Windows quiet hours always turned on

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams

On my Win10 desktop PC, the Microsoft Teams desktop app always shows "Windows quiet hours is enabled, so you won't get notifications for Calls and messages in Teams".

I tried everything for switching off Quiet Hours in Windows:

- Using the Settings app
- Using the Registry (HKCU/SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\QuitHours)
- Using GPEDIT (User Policies)

Until recently, Teams only showed this text but showed notifications anyhow, but it seems that they fixed that bug and now it takes Windows Quiet Hours seriously or what Teams thinks are Quit Hours.

But I had no luck. My MS Teams version is 1.3.0030866 and my Windows version is 20H2 build 19042.662
I am also using Teams on a second machine (with Quit Hours turned off as well, but without this bug) and on an IOS phone.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Teams after making your changes (as it usually does not close and is still open in the backgroud)

Comment: Yes I did. I made sure than no Teams process was still running

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue and can't figure it out.

Comment: @Pedro: No, I didn't. I upgraded my PC and installed a clean version of Win11 (for other reasons), afterwards the problem was gone.